# Ionic 3 trigger Popover from another button?

Tags: angular, ionic3

Is it possible to trigger a popover in Ionic 3 using a secondary button?

For example I want my popover to be bound to this button.

```
<button ion-button
       (click)="presentPopover($event)">
    BUTTON 1 
</button>
```

but also want to trigger that popover from another button.

```
<button ion-button icon-only 
       (click)="clicking this fires button 1">
    <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
BUTTON2
</button>
```

Any idea how this is possible?

Comment: Yes you can but popover always shows in center of screen when you open it using second components

Comment: ^^ Check out the doc: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/popover/PopoverController/ -- "In order to position the popover relative to the element clicked, a click event needs to be passed into the options of the the `present` method. If the event is not passed, the popover will be positioned in the center of the current view. See the usage section for an example of passing this event."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to simulate click-event for **BUTTON 1** on click **BUTTON 2**

**.html:**

```
<button id="btn1" ion-button (click) = "presentPopover($event)">
    BUTTON 1 
</button>

<button ion-button icon-only (click) = "clickBtn1()">
    <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>
    BUTTON2
</button>
```

**.ts:**

```
clickBtn1() {
   document.getElementById('btn1').click(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I guess I was too focussed on looking for some Angular  way to do this I overlooked simple JS. Much appreciated .